# excluding hidden files only in a particular directory

Tags: rsync

I’m trying to synchronise my home folder with a usb disk.

I would like to ignore the hidden files and directory in my home folder but only in this directory, I still need to synchronise the hidden files in the sub-directories contained in my home folder.

I tried to use this option : `--exclude="/home/valentin/.*" --exclude "/home/valentin/.*/"` but rsync synchronises everything, even /home/valentin/.cache/ for example

What option do I need to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below command.

```
rsync -avz --exclude '/.*' /home/valentin/ /destination_folder
```

Answer (score 0):

The path rsync uses for --exclude is relative to the /source

```
rsync -avz --exclude '.*' ~ /destination
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This will exclude all hidden files